# Nullpointer exception in my LinkedList

Tags: java, list, exception, insert, nullpointerexception

I have a List class where I have this insert function. The list is sorting numbers in the list decreasingly. When I insert the following statement `Ape ={ 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 6 }`, I get a nullpointer exception.

```
public List<E> insert (E d){
    Node<E> newNode= new Node<E>(d);
    if(isEmpty()){
        current=first=last=newNode;
        numberOfNodes++;
        return this;
    }

    if(newNode.data.compareTo(first.data)>0){
        first.prior=newNode;
        newNode.next=first;
        first= current = newNode;
        numberOfNodes++;
        return this;
    }

    setFirst();
    while(current.next != null && newNode.data.compareTo(current.data)<0){
        current=current.next;
    }
    if(current.next==null){
        current.next=newNode;
        newNode.prior=current;
        last=current=newNode;
        numberOfNodes++;
        return this;
    }
    else{
        current.prior.next=newNode;
        newNode.prior=current.prior;
        newNode.next=current;
        current.prior=newNode;
        current=newNode;
        numberOfNodes++;
        return this;
    }
}
```

I am getting a nullpointer exception at current.prior.next=newNode;

Can someone help me with this?

Many thanks!

Comment: yeah, `current` or `current.prior` is null. What does you debugging tell you?

Comment: current.prior is not null, it is current.prior.next that causes the trouble!

Comment: Please prepare a runnable example demonstrating the problem if you want to help us help you.

Comment: How can I do this? I am sorry, I am new to StackOverflow :S

Comment: Include a main method, so that we can simply copy-paste your code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: If `current.prior.next` is throwing a `NullPointerException`, then either:

1) `current` is null, so accessing the `prior` field is impossible, or
2) `current.prior` is null, so accessing the `next` field is impossible.

It should be really easy to test which of these is the case.  (For example, put `current = current` on a line, to see if that line throws the `NullPointerException`.)

Comment: If the problem is at `current.prior.next=newNode;` then `current` or `current.prior` is `null`. `next` is the reference you are setting, it is allowed to be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

The element that is null actually has to be current.prior if current was null you would have had a nullpointer at the preceding if.
This means the node you are looking at does not have a prior node.
This will become apparent when you step through the code.

Also:

- There is actually a LinkedList class in Java, why not use that
  instead?
- Please don't do chained assignments like `current=first=last=newNode;`
- Do you really need all those fields to be member fields?
- Add some JavaDoc or divide this method in submethods